# Add "required" to select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Country select box that display a State select box if the USA is selected. I am using the following jQuery to achieve this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#country').change(function(){
        $('.state').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

Is there a way that I can amend the above to also add the required attribute to the State select box if the USA is selected?

The State select box is within the following DIV

```
<div id="USA" class="state" style="display:none">

</div>
```

Many thanks,

John

Comment: That looks like it's hiding the `.state` field in all cases? In any case, you can use `prop()` to achieve this

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - It's hidden unless the USA is selected in the Country select box. Can you help me with the code needed using prop()? I am a jQuery newbie! Thanks

Comment: That's not what the code you've shown in the question appears to be doing, but the logic you require is simply `$field.prop('required', true)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've amended my original post to include the DIV that's used to hide the State select box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method for that:

```js
$("#country").on("change", function() {
  let $state = $("#state");
  
  if ($(this).val() == "EUA") {
    $state.prop("required", "required");
  }
  else {
    $state.prop("required", null);
  }
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <select id="country">
    <option>EUA</option>
    <option>Other</option>
  </select>

  <select id="state">
    <option></option>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
  </select>
  
  <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

- `prop("required", "required")` to add the property;
- `prop("required", null)` to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check for the selected value first, then you could use `prop()/removeProp()` :

```
$(function() {
    $('#country').change(function(){
        var selected_value = $(this).val();
        var state   = $(".state");
        var related_elem = $('#' + selected_value);

        if( selected_value === 'USA' ){
            state.prop('required', true).show();
            related_elem.show();
        }else{
            state.removeProp('required').hide();
            related_elem.hide();
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
```